# How to make my web to open at certain scroll height

Tags: web, scroll

My web's important content is at 300 pixels from the top so I want it to open directly at that height giving the user the option to scroll up if they want.
Which is the easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one alternative. I create an anchor and then make it load directly to it. I didn't want to use anchors but as no one answered me...

```
<body onload="location.href ='#home'">
  <a id="home"></a>
```

EDIT: Here's what i was looking for!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Scrolldown() {
window.scroll(0,100); 
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
</script>
```